# Is the “template” a member of the SubscribeOptions?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the source code of node_handle.h, Line 252, `ops.template init<M>(topic, queue_size);`

The link is http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/roscpp/html/node__handle_8h_source.html#l00249.

I don't understand why the developer wrote `ops.template`. To my understanding, the template is a key word, the way that `ops.template` shows looks like the template is a member or method of the ops (template struct).

Does anyone know why the developer put it in this way?  I am very confused about it.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308820/is-the-%E2%80%9Ctemplate%E2%80%9D-a-member-of-the-subscribeoptions?/) by [FungY](https://answers.ros.org/users/31426/fungy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-11-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, `template` is not a member of `ops`.

---

The line of code that you refer to is actually (from [here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/eb7e686a9a58109087c956eed3cfa6f2ed3eec3d/clients/roscpp/include/ros/node_handle.h#L248-L255)):

```
ops.template init<M>(topic, queue_size);
```

In this line, the `init(..)` method is called on the `ops` object. So it's essentially `ops.init<M>(..)`.

`template` is indeed a keyword, but this syntax is needed here to make sure the compiler understands this calls the templated `init(..)`.

[This SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676190) quotes the C++ 03 standard, saying:

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or `->` in a postfix-expression, or after nested-name-specifier in a qualified-id, and the postfix-expression or qualified-id explicitly depends on a template-parameter (14.6.2), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword `template`. Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-17**:
Note that this is more a generic C++ question than something specific to ROS.

**Comment by [FungY](https://answers.ros.org/users/31426/fungy/) on 2018-11-18**:
Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I will take a look in the template syntax. Thanks again.